# How to set and edge's arrow size on JGraph?

Tags: java, jgraph

I am using JGraph to draw some simples graphs. Right now I want the arrows in the end of the edges to be bigger. I have already set their shape by using the `mxConstants.STYLE_START/ENDARROW` key and the appropriate `mxConstants.ARROW_X` value, according to the [API's doc](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/java/docs/).

In the documentation they say that *mxConstants.ARROW_SIZE* can be used to set the arrow's size, but I still have not found exactly how. Since its a static variable in the class, I tried

```
mxConstants.ARROW_SIZE = 100;
```

within the `beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate()` statements, both before and after the edges creation but nothing works. The size remains the same. Perhaps I am missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `mxConstants.DEFAULT_MARKERSIZE` to the value you want should do what you expect.